# Do all moments of order $k $ uniquely determine the distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X $ be a random variable and $g $ its probability generating function.

I was reasoning about how the probability generating functions uniquely determine a distribution, because you can recover $P(X = k) $ with the $k $-the derivative of $g $.. Then I thought of how you can also get $X $'s factorial moments of order $k $ by derivating $g $ and evaluating at a specific point.

Then I wondered if knowing $E[X^k], \forall k \in \Bbb{N} $ uniquely determines the distribution. I have no idea how to prove/disprove this and hence any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Don't know the proof but if the support of $X$ is bounded then $E(X^k), \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ uniquely determines the distribution.

Comment: Is $X$ restricted to the non-negative integers?

Comment: Do you assume that $X$ is discrete...?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your plan is that the probability generating function has a zero radius of convergence, and hence power series methods of evaluating derivatives break down.

The uniqueness of solutions to the moment problem is  discussed in a [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem) and the articles it points to.  If your r.v. is bounded the answer is *yes*.  If your r.v. is not bounded, the answer is sometimes *yes* (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman%27s_condition) for instance), and sometimes *no* (as in the case of counterexamples given in textbooks), and sometimes *we don't know*.

Answer (score 0):

If two distributions have exactly the same moments one cannot deduce that the distributions are identical at almost all points. There are various cases (for example lognormal distributions) that all the moments exists but still the moment generating function doesn't. However it's a basic result that equal moment generating functions imply equal distributions at almost all points.